# Older Version(s) Available Still...?

Tags: versions

New group member here, and potential Ubuntu user :)
I have an older notebook that can only run WinXP.
Is there a version of Ubuntu I can DL to a bootable flash drive to meet these sys reqs?
Can't get the OS to boot, and haven't tried in 5 or so years, so I don't have any sys details to give, but I will unearth it this next week and research the model #.
I do remember it was a Dell hehe
Thanks In Advance- :-)

-Scotty

Comment: Hi, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1236523/edit) your question to include the target system's specs.

Comment: please add information about your pc,brand-type-ram-cpu-chipset-grapicks card as this will help in giving you a good answer to your question.

Comment: You will probably want a Lubuntu or Xubuntu or something similar.  I'm running Lubuntu on a P4 with 1 GB of ram.  Make sure if your computer is 32bit only or 64 bit.  Can run 32 bit on both, but can run 64 only on 64 type.

Comment: With Ubuntu you don't want older versions, but would want lighter type of new versions.

Comment: Hey, THANKS for all the very helpful responses!

Comment: I can't seem to figure out these new tagging procedures, and the thread is vague to me, so I'm just gonna throw it out there and hope it sticks :)
Hey, THANKS for all the very helpful responses!
OS won't boot, so I can't get into the sys details or even BIOS and POST setup.
It has been awhile since I attempted last, but my newer notebook took a HUGE crap and was hoping to resurrect this older one :)
I'll unearth it and get the model # and see if I can't get the sys info on it.
Meanwhile, I am very grateful for all of your responses.
Think I'm gonna like this community... :)

Comment: @kortewegdevries Did, thanks for your response :)

Comment: @trond hansen I updated my question - thanks for your quick response :)

Comment: @crip659 Thank You! I did not know any of that! Can't remember if 32 or 64 but I'll find out next week :)

Comment: please add information about your pc,brand-type-ram-cpu-chipset-grapicks card as this will help in giving you a good answer to your question.

Comment: @abu_bua nice copy &paste ;)

Comment: we need info especialy about your graphicscard, cpu processor, ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, old versions ARE still available, it's just that they won't show up on the official Ubuntu website. The oldest version currently supported is 16.04 Xenial, but if you want something much older than 16.04 Xenial, such as 12.04 Precise, then go to releases.ubuntu.com

Comment: Old unsupported versions should only be suggested to see difference/fun or very specific need.  Not for used as a person's OS.

Comment: Hey, Thanks, Aaron for your response, Aaron :)

Comment: I updated my original question to explain a little more of my prob. I was hoping to get a version that could still get online with...

Comment: Mark it if it helps you!